# Hidden custom fields after push upgrade

Tags: custom-field, push-upgrade

Our customers were using our managed package. Later on, we added few custom fields into the Account object. We then pushed the upgrades to our Client's orgs. But, after the push upgrade, the newly created custom fields were set as hidden.

What is the reason behind this? What can we do to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

If by hidden, you mean that the new fields were missing from the Account layout, this is a design decision made by Salesforce. Various ideas to address this have been posted - this one is 6 years old [Enable upgrade of managed app items unchanged by customer](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpMpAAK) - but there seems little momentum to change this.

To work around it its either manual updating or write your own metadata API based tool to push the changes. But in both cases you will need access rights to your customer's orgs.

Comment: Thanks Keith. By hidden, we mean that Field Accessibility of our custom fields were hidden by default.

Comment: @Rupali It is possible to include permission sets and profiles in your managed package and if they are being used by your customers the settings for any new fields will be updated. (Though the fields will still not be presented because of the layouts.) But if your customers are using locally created permission sets and profiles new fields default to hidden in those.